# play 2.6.3 detects database from application.conf when running but not during tests

Tags: java, junit, playframework-2.0

I've been having problems using JUnit tests to verify that a database is correctly working with the UCanAccess Driver. When I run the server normally in IntelliJ IDEA, I am told that the database pool is set up correctly:

```
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[info] p.a.d.DefaultDBApi - Database [default] connected at jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/Users/me/Documents/testdb.accdb
```

However, when I run JUnit tests through IntelliJ, I get the following error:

```
Configuration error: Configuration error[Driver not found: [org.h2.Driver}]]

at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:155)
at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:984)
at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase$$anonfun$driver$1.apply(Databases.scala:114)
at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase$$anonfun$driver$1.apply(Databases.scala:108)
...
```

I assume the above error is being caused by Play defaulting to using the default database configuration, i.e. an h2 database.

How can I make it so JUnit tests recognize my database driver rather than defaulting to using an h2 database?

Tests:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import play.db.Database;
import play.db.Databases;
import play.db.evolutions.Evolution;
import play.db.evolutions.Evolutions;

import java.sql.Connection;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;


public class ApplicationTest {

    Database database;


    @Before
    public void setupDatabase() {
        // Gets default database in this case
        database = Databases.inMemory();

        System.out.println(database.getConnection());
        Evolutions.applyEvolutions(database, Evolutions.forDefault(new Evolution(
                1,
                "create table teste (id bigint not null, name varchar(255));",
                "drop table test;"
        )));
    }


    @After
    public void shutdownDatabase() {
        Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions(database);
        database.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void databaseCRUD() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = database.getConnection();
        conn.prepareStatement("insert into test values (10, 'testing')").execute();
        // Make sure that there is a tenth element in the table
        assertTrue(
                conn.prepareStatement("select * from test where id = 10 and name = 'testing'")
                        .executeQuery().next()
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the database using the driver you need.
Here is a postgres example:

```
val dbUrl = sys.env.getOrElse("DATABASE_URL", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/app?user=user&password=password")
val database = Databases("org.postgresql.Driver", dbUrl, "testingzzz")
```

Use the correct url and driver, and you are good to go.